# What dice system to choose?

Tags: game-recommendation, dice

Is there a chart that classifies the different ways to use dice and skills (or whatever values the characters in the system have) to determine the success or failure of an action?

The following criteria interest me:

- Randomness: What has more impact on success: the die roll or the skill?
- Paradoxes: Are there circumstances when having a higher skill leads to decreased chances of success?
- Success Levels: Does the system permit different levels of success/failure?
- Complexity: How much time must I spend calculating or using lookup tables to determine the result?

Comment: I have no clue what you are looking for, please edit to clarify.

Comment: I want a comparison of dice-systems - e.g. D20 is more random as X. This should help to decide for a system that matches my own needs.

Comment: Is there a difference between "dice systems" and "game systems" in your question?  It seems like a very wide open question.

Comment: You're out of luck. There are as many ways to generate interrelated random numbers with dice as there are ways a language can use sounds to form meaningful words. New dice systems are invented all the time. In fact, inventing and testing new dice systems is a significant part of modern game design.

Comment: This is duplicate-ish of [3d6 vs a d20: What is the effect of a different probability curve?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/3d6-vs-a-d20-what-is-the-effect-of-a-different-probability-curve). Also, how can you determine if something is more random? Those interested in some math about randomness, check out [Understanding "randomness"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956478/understanding-randomness) on StackOverflow.

Comment: ... and I'm with @Pat Ludwig: this is ambiguous as to whether it refers to a "dice system" or a "game system".

Comment: I think that this question is asking something along the lines of "how does the die rolling game mechanic impact game play", which IMO is still too open ended, but probably lends its self to a great deal more tightening. (As, for example http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/earthdawn-dice-roll-probabilities and http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/3d6-vs-a-d20-what-is-the-effect-of-a-different-probability-curve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, this is pretty wide ranging, and as a result there's nothing out there that does all that comprehensively.  John Kim has a starter comparison and explanation of different dice approaches that might provide you a good starting point... http://www.darkshire.net/jhkim/rpg/systemdesign/dice-motive.html

Comment: Ah, that in line I was looking for. This article does define similar criteria for the evaluation. Thanks for this hint.