# There was a system that had "Step-Damage" I am seeking the game systems name

Tags: product-identification

The step damage system was something like this:

For step 7 you would roll 2d6 as the average is 3.5 per die and that adds up to 7 (for non exploding or re-rolling dice). With exploding dice this is d12.

Then, each time you rolled the maximum number on a die you rolled that die again.
The step chart was supposed to roll the number in the middle more often.
It was more linear than a bell curve.

While this seems a poor explanation, I hope that it will help.

TLDR:I am seeking the system that has the step damage as it's damage system.

Comment: This sounds loosely familiar, but I don't know where to start looking for it. I know that some of the WH40k RPG things do this in execution, but their goal behind how they work is different, so you might want to see if Fantasy Flight Games did something that looks familiar to you. That said, it's not where I think I've seen it before, but I've seen a lot of games, so if you could give me any more information it'd make it easier for me to look through my piles of stuff.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As reflected in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/earthdawn-dice-roll-probabilities), I think Earthdawn is the system you're looking for. It could also be [Alternity](http://geek-related.com/2011/05/02/alternity-the-system/), but that system explicitly doesn't use d10s.

Comment: I thought Alternity had high-level bonuses and maluses represented with 1d10.

Comment: All the evidence I've seen says you're mistaken about that. Here's the Wiki page on the game: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternity#Dice_Mechanics. And here's an IRC log from the creators back in the day explaining why they chose not to include them. http://www.alternityrpg.net/irclog.php?file=RichardBaker

Comment: @Jadasc fair enough!  i knew that if it used d10's at all,it  would only be in its bonus/malus slider.  it's been a while since I played alternity, hence the confusion.  such a great system though.